# How to know once all odata calls have finished on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have multiple odata calls on one screen and they are not in a batch call. I want to trigger an event after all the calls have been finished. How do i do so?

Comment: To know if all calls have been completed is a tricky business. Are you using just tables or List ? If yes then there is a way

Comment: I have mainly tables on screen. For lets say i have 5 tables reading data from 5 different entity sets , on a single screen. There are 5 different odata calls going for them. So how do i know once all calls are finished?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your model, which will get called each time the model is finished with a request.

`this.getView().getModel().attachRequestCompleted(function(){console.log("complete!");});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Event `batchRequestCompleted(oControlEvent)` of your `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel`. From the documentation: The `batchRequestCompleted` event is fired, after a request has been completed (includes receiving a response), no matter whether the request succeeded or not.

[V2 OData Model - batchRequestCompleted](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel%23events/batchRequestCompleted)

Comment: I don't have a single call.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Tables, you can use the [updateFinished](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#event:updateFinished) event to notify when each read completes.

```
<Table headerText="tab1"
        updateFinished="onTableUpdate"
        items="{/Collection}"...

     <Table headerText="tab2"
        updateFinished="onTableUpdate"
        items="{/Collection}"...

     <Table headerText="tab3"
        updateFinished="onTableUpdate"
        items="{/Collection}"...
```

To keep a check you will have to maintain flags when you initialize

```
onInit: function () {
        this.oComplete = {
            "tab1" : false,
            "tab2" : false,
            "tab3" : false
        }
```

And you will need a method which sets these flags to true when each of the tables complete their update.

```
onTableUpdate: function(oEvent){
        var oTable= oEvent.getSource(),
            sText = oTable.getHeaderText();
        this.oComplete[sText] = true;
        //Check if all read's are complete
        if(this.oComplete["tab1"] && this.oComplete["tab2"] && this.oComplete["tab3"]){
            this._updateFinished();
        }

    },

    _updateFinished : function(){
        //Add you logic which should run after all call's complete
        ...
    }
```

Once it's all done, _updateFinished will be triggered.

Note: The updateFinished event works for all controls that extend sap.m.ListBase